# Microphone Input Playback (Fmod studio API)

Tags: audio, fmod

I got my microphone input working fine in my custom engine. I am getting all the levels, dominant frequency data i need from the microphone. The issue is i'm still hearing microphone playback. I tried muting the channel. If i do that i end up getting absolutely no data. Any solution to this?

I am using getMeteringInfo for the peak values.

Is it possible to have the metering set to Pre Fader? Because I think it is post fader at the moment. But at the same time I would want to monitor the signal after applying a microphone filter that filters out all the frequencies outside the (20-150Hz) range.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the metering for any point in the graph of DSP nodes, in the case of the fader you can meter both "pre" and "post". The following code snippet will fetch the fader from a given 'channel', enable metering on it and return both "pre" and "post" fader values.

```
FMOD::DSP *fader;
channel->getDSP(FMOD_CHANNELCONTROL_DSP_FADER, &fader);
fader->setMeteringEnabled(true, true);

FMOD_DSP_METERING_INFO preFaderMeter, postFaderMeter;
fader->getMeteringInfo(&preFaderMeter, &postFaderMeter);
```